# Integrate Wordpress Post with Cakephp3

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working on cakephp 3.x and want to display blogs section on my site. I want to use WordPress feature in my site.

I have installed WordPress 4 on my local server, then I have imported tables of WordPress into cake's database and put the WordPress folder into webroot folder of Cakephp.

In app controller's initialize() function I have put this code as follows:

```
    global $wpdb;
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/webroot/blog/wp-config.php");
```

So that I can embed WordPress into cakephp (seems this is not helpful).

I have tried this tutorial but not success on this [Tutorial Link](https://sarasotawebpros.com/is-it-possible-to-integrate-cakephp-and-wordpress-woocommerce/).

I know in this tutorial Wordpress folder is placed out of webroot folder and I have tried that too.

When I run the site using **http:example.com/blog**

It is asking for blog controller and I understand this is because of as blog controller is not present in **src/controller** folder.

I have tried .htaccess code as per suggested in tutorial but no success on that.
Can anyone help me out from this problem? Please let me know the required steps for integration.

Comment: This probably isn't the best way to do it (install WP within a Cake app). Instead, install them in separate directories. There are numerous answers for `install <Cake|Wordpress> in separate directory` that should be able to direct you. (P.S. And they definitely should not be sharing a database.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "API"

```
<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');

$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Or try WP API ;)