# Integrating wordpress to symfony 3 based website

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have a website that uses Symfony3 and am trying to integrate a wordpress blog under `www.website.com/blog`.

So what I've done so far is create a `blog` folder, under the Symfony `web` folder, which contains the wordpress files.

I've then added a rewrite rule, in the `web/` directory's `.htaccess` file so that when we are under `blog/`, Symfony's url rewriting won't do anything :

```
# Passing through the Url rewriting for all blog/ urls
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/$1 [PT]
```

So far it's good. I can access the admin section and everything but the problem is that when I try to access `www.website.com/blog` or even `www.website.com/blog/index.php` I only get the list of files in the folder and not the actual front page.

[image]

And here is the `.htaccess` file from `blog/` folder that was created when I launched the wordpress installation script:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xxx/web/blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /xxx/web/blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: Please check if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555960/integrate-wordpress-posts-into-cakephp-3-site

Comment: @DeepKakkar unfortunately it didn't help ..

Comment: @Moucheg did you find the solution? as i am into same problem. Please help.

Comment: i just got it working.. in the /web .htaccess file , comment DirectoryIndex app.php . Because, this is redirecting all request in any directory to app.php file.. now same is happening in /blog . As there is no app.php file in wordpress (installed in /blog), so showing all files

Comment: @Dip Sorry mate I don't remember what I did there anymore...

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you have access to the sites-available's configuration file for your site, i.e. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf`.

And add a `<Directory>` for your blog with the WordPress rules:

```
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/web/blog>

            DirectoryIndex index.php

            # BEGIN WordPress
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    RewriteEngine On
                    RewriteBase /blog/
                    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
            </IfModule>

           # END WordPress

    </Directory>
```

Note: I have added `DirectoryIndex index.php` by myself because my Symfony have a `DirectoryIndex app.php` or `DirectoryIndex disabled`.

---

If you don't have access to your configuration file, probably you need to add the `DirectoryIndex index.php` to your `.httaccess` but then your configuration site and the `.httaccess` of Symfony should allow this directive, e.g., they should contain `AllowOverride All` or `AllowOverride Indexes FileInfo`.